# Java - subtract a scalar from the RGB values of an image

Tags: java, image, rgb

Using Java EDIT: and a good Image Library BESIDES ImageMagick/JMagick:

I want to subtract a scalar (say 100) from the RGB values of **ALL** pixels, (bottoming out at zero). This is effectively darkening the image.

For example, for a given pixel with **R: 20 G: 103 B: 200**, after this subtraction that pixel should be **R: 0 G: 3 B: 100** (again I want to quickly and efficiently perform this on ALL pixels, not just one)

I have already tried using ImageMagick and gotten imprecise results - it's vital that the subtraction is accurate and there are no rounding errors and the such. Any other libraries that would be good at this? Are there other options that don't deal with iterating over arrays of RGB values?

Comment: Instead of subtracting you might consider multiplying by a number less than one - this will result in a more natural darkening.

Comment: The goal isn't too darken for aesthetic purposes - it's for a processing purpose so I definitely want to do the subtraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BufferedImage` class has both a `getRGB()` and `setRGB()` method that can act on individual pixels or arrays of pixels.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Comment: wouldn't it be rather inefficient/time consuming to iterate over an entire array of pixels to subtract 100?

Comment: I think I read somewhere (cant find link) that using `Raster` might be quicker. However, an image is an array of pixels, how could you ever accurately perform your transformation without iterating and apply your subtraction to all pixels (either by you doing it or by some abstract interface that you might be using)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
If R or G or B is negative, then you can make it 0.

```
//At first get the RGB value
int RGB=getRGB(x,y);
int R=RGB>>>16-100; //shift by 16 bit to get the R value
if(R<0) R=0;
int G=(RGB<<<8)>>>16-100;//clear the preceding numbers than shift 16 bit
if(G<0) G=0;
int B=(RGB<<<16)>>>16-100;
if(B<0)B=0;
int newRGB=R<<<16+G<<<8+B;
setRGB(x,y,newRGB);
```